# VS2013 LINK1104 Cannot find winhttp.lib

Tags: c++, windows, sockets, visual-studio-2013, udp

I'm writing C++ code that involves UDP communication in 64-bit Windows 8.  I am having difficulty building for the `x64` configuration, although the `Win32` configuration works fine.  The problem lies at the top of my code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
```

When I build in `Win32` configuration, everything works fine.  But when I build in `x64` configuration, I get the following linker error:

```
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Lib\x64\winhttp.lib'
```

I've put the full path to `winhttp.lib` in the project properties > VC++ Directories > Library Directories field, and I've even included `winhttp.lib` in the project directly, but with no luck.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I can build fine in the `x64 DEBUG` configuration, but not `x64 RELEASE`.  I'm working by way through the respective configuration properties, but I don't know why `RELEASE` works but not `DEBUG`.

Comment: Distinguish between "c:\program files" and "c:\program files (x86)".  Do *not* use wsock32.lib, it was meant for programs that were written for Windows 3.x

Comment: What do you mean by "distinguish between"?  I have verified that I am using ws2_32.lib, but I'll remove the possibility of using wsock32.lib for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I can vaguely remember having messed up paths with different Visual Studio versions / Platform SDKs installed. Do you have multiple installations? Maybe you need to fix your search paths manually.

And btw, with VS2013 Express on my home computer, I don't even have v7.0, only 7.0A.